# Too much exported symbols for a project compiled with CMake and MinGW

Tags: cmake, mingw

I'm trying to compile [libzint](https://github.com/zint/zint) (a barcode generator) for Windows using CMake and MinGW. The aim is to avoid Visual Studio dependencies. All run fine except that the generated .dll file contains too much exported symbols. I should have only ZBarcode_* functions but in fact pretty much anything that is declared as a variable/constant gets exported (and the resulting .dll file have no version information, I think this is strange.)

Here's how I did the job :

1. git clone from github repository in D:\Projects\Zint
2. installed cmake in C:\CMake
3. installed mingw in C:\MinGW
4. started cmake-gui, browsed to D:\Projects\Zint
5. clicked "Configure", choosed "MinGW Makefiles" in the list and "specify native compilers", next I specified the full path to c:\mingw\bin\mingw32-gcc.exe (to be sure...)
6. Clicked "Configure". It succeeded but it added some variables in red because dependencies where not met (PNG and QT but I don't want them and zint is fine without them)
7. clicked "Configure" again, everything turned white
8. clicked "Generate"
9. closed the cmake-gui
10. started a console prompt
11. overrode the path variable environment to C:\mingw\bin only
12. went to "D:\Projects\Zint" and ran "mingw32-make" then "mingw32-make install"
13. the libzint.dll and zint.exe were deployed to "C:\Program Files\zint-package\bin"

I used [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to have a look at the exported functions and saw that in addition to few ZBarcode_* functions there were also around 400 other symbols and given the source code I saw that these symbols are in fact constants, arrays and other internals of libzint.

Do you know how to configure or tweak things to avoid all these exports ?

Many thanks for your help, regards.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the headers for any macros that contain `dllexport`. If you find one or more, check that it's not malfunctioning.

Another possibility is that all classes are being exported, instead of just the few functions that are necessary.

If you have `grep`, do `grep -nr dllexport *`. This will recursively look in all files. For every hit, it will print the file name, line number, and contents of the line.